# Using has_tag() outside loop

Tags: loop, conditional-tags, tags

I want to if the check next post has a specific tag. I tried the following code, but it is not working because `has_tag()` only works in the loop. I want to use it outside the loop.

```
<?php if ( has_tag( 'mario', $post->ID ) ) : ?>
my content
<?php endif; ?>
```

The following code lists the tags from post, but I don't know how to make it work with an `if()` / `else()` condition:

```
global $post;
foreach ( get_the_tags( $post->ID ) as $tag ) {
    echo $tag->name . ', ';
}
```

Comment: What is the context? Why are your trying to do this? What is the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

The [**`has_tag()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag) conditional does *not* have to be used inside the Loop; it can be passed a `$post` *object* as a second parameter:

```
has_tag( $tag, $post );
```

Since `has_tag()` defaults to the *current* post, you simply need to pass it the object for the next adjacent post. Fortunately, WordPress provides a function to retrieve adjacent posts: [**`get_adjacent_post()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post):

```
get_adjacent_post( $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous );
```

The `$in_same_cat` parameter defaults to `false`, the `$excluded_categories` parameter defaults to `''`, and the `$previous` parameter defaults to `true`. So, we just need to change that third parameter to `false`, to retrieve the *next* post, instead of the *previous* post:

```
get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
```

Combining it with your `has_tag()` conditional:

```
if ( has_tag( 'mario', get_adjacent_post( false, '', true ) ) {
    // Next post has the 'mario' post tag;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: yes, you're right about `has_tag`. I was wrong. Its a simple solution you've mentioned above. my wrong information was the only problem. otherwise I already was using `get_adjacent_post` to get next post id. Thanks you

Comment: If Chip's answer worked for you, then please mark it as correct using the green tick next to the left of the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
$post_id = 123;
$posttags = get_the_tags($post_id);
if (!is_wp_error($posttags) && $posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        if ($tag->name == 'mario') {
            echo 'yup';
        }
    }
}
```

What you're doing is:

- Grabbing the tags
- If there are any tags, running each of them through a foreach
- If one of those foreach instances match the case of `mario`, doing something (in this case, echoing 'yup')

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks, its working. but at mario page its printing both yup and nope. at other pages it is showing "nope" only, which means its correct here.

Comment: actually when I use for current post id. it works fine. the problem is I want to use it for $next_post->ID at mario page it prints both yup and nope

Comment: `$posttags = get_the_tags($next_post->id);
if (!is_wp_error($posttags) && $posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        if ($tag->name == 'mario') {
            echo 'yup';
        }
        elseif($tag->name !== 'mario') {
            echo 'nope';
        }
    }
}`
I've tried this one too, but still its printing "yup nope" at  post having mario tag. where as at pages with other tags, it prints nope only, which is fine. The problem is occurring only on mario tagged posts.

Comment: It runs through *each* available tag for the post, so if `mario` is available, then it would print `yup` in addition to `nope` if any others available in the post do not match. So - if you don't want anything to print on tags that don't match `mario`, then just take out the `else` statement (revised above)